# list of formulas created with lapply() includes strings like <environment: 0x000000001c0809c8> after formulae

Tags: r

I want to feed a function a string that corresponds to the right hand side of a formula, and then turn that string into a list of formulas where the column names of a data.frame are the left hand side values of the formula. To do this, I use the following structure:

```
form <- "a + b + c + d"
t <- matrix(runif(20),nrow=10,ncol=2)
colnames(t) <- c("col1","col2")
form.new2 <- lapply(colnames(t),function(x) as.formula(paste(x,sep="~",form)))
form.new2
```

For me, this returns:

```
[[1]]
col1 ~ a + b + c + d
<environment: 0x000000001c0809c8>

[[2]]
col2 ~ a + b + c + d
<environment: 0x000000001c07d350>
```

The code does close to what I expected it to do, but I have no idea what these tags are at the en, as I've never encountered them before. I think I can get rid of them with stringr or something like that, but 1. I'd rather not clutter the function more if I don't have to, and 2. I'm curious about what these are and where they come from. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Those tags aren't really there. Note that what R chooses to display when you print the value of a variable isn't necessarily the same as what the variable actually contains. In this case what get's run is `stats:::print.formula()`

However, all formulas track in which environment they were created. If that environment is the global environment, the "tag" doesn't show up.

If you want to set the environment to the global environment (to get the "default" behavior), use

```
my_formula <- function(x) as.formula(paste(x,sep="~",form), env=globalenv())
form.new2 <- lapply(colnames(t), my_formula)
form.new2
# [[1]]
# col1 ~ a + b + c + d
# 
# [[2]]
# col2 ~ a + b + c + d
```